# String/ Array situations c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I don't understand what's wrong with it exactly. The num of tries in the end comes out to be 9, even with a while loop. I want it check of the guess is one of the coordinates in string, but it never works. :/

And where would i move the if statement?

```
int main() {
int guesses, destroy, numAttempts = 11;
string guess, i;
string coordinate[3] = {"B1", "C4", "D3"};

cout << "Enter in a coordinate between A-1 and D-4 (i.e. C4): ";
cin >> guess;

guesses = 0;
destroy = 0;
while (guess != coodinate[i] && guesses < numAttempts - 1) {
    cout << "Target missed. Try again: ";
     cin >> guess;
     guesses++;;
}
if (guess != coordinate[i])
    cout << "Failed!";
else
    cout << "Congrats!";

  /*if (guess == coordinate) {
     cout << "Target hit! Next target: ";
     cin >> guess;
 destroy++;
 guesses++;

 }
 */

}
```

Comment: Considering the typo Bigood caught, is this *really* the code?

Comment: `i` should be declared an `int`, not a `string`...

Answer (score 2):

You are forgetting to increment `i`.. `i++` (at least, I assume you are?). 
Could be part of the mistake. 
And if you do have to increment i, make sure it doesn't go out of bounds..

```
   guess = input ;
   guesses = 0;
   while (guesses < numAttempts  && guess != coodinate[i] ) { 
     cout << "Target missed. Try again: ";
     cin >> guess;
     guesses++;
     i = (i+1)%3;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped a bit,but my main problem is:

Comment: "error C2677: binary '[' : no global operator found which takes type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
"

Comment: It's happening at the while

Comment: Um.. the while looks fine.. I don't think you are posting the actual code :P

Comment: Lol. I just have to find another way to get it to loop.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a typo here :

```
while (guess != coodinate[i] && guesses < numAttempts - 1) 
              //coordinate[i]
```

Try :

```
while ((guess != coordinate[i]) && (guesses < (numAttempts - 1))) 
//Parenthesis are not mandatory
```

Plus, as others pointed out, you're not looking for the value `guess` in all the array `coordinate`, as you don't increment `i`.

Comment: I upvoted it, but I think the extra parentheses really are unnecessary. They only serve to increase the character count.

Comment: @StoryTeller I added these for clarity, I'm not into C++ anymore: I wasn't sure if they were useful or not. I'll edit my answer to point it out.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to learn to create small one-purpose functions and combine them together.

```
#include <set> // because you have a set of targets...
#include <string> // used to represent a target

using Target = std::string;

static Target const MissedTarget = "";

static bool isGuessCorrect(Target const& guess,
                           std::set<Target> const& targets)
{
    return targets.count(guess);
}

// Returns the target hit (if any), or MissedTarget otherwise
static Target tryOnce(std::set<Target> const& targets) {
    std::cout << "Enter in a coordinate between A-1 and D-4 (i.e. C4): ";

    std::string guess;
    if (std::cin >> guess) {
        if (isGuessCorrect(guess, targets)) { return guess; }

        return MissedTarget;
    }

    // Something that could not (unfortunately) be parsed,
    // we need to clear std::cin
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limit<size_t>::max(), '\n');

    return MissedTarget;
}

static bool tryFewTimes(size_t const tries, std::set<Target>& targets) {
    for (size_t n = 0; n != tries; ++n) {
        Target const target = tryOnce(targets);

        if (target == MissedTarget) {
            std::cout << "Missed! Try again!\n";
            continue;
        }

        targets.erase(target);

        std::cout << "Congratz! You got " << target
                  << "! Only " << targets.size() << " remaining\n";
        return true;
    }

    std::cout << "You flunked it, can't always win :(\n";
    return false;
}


int main() {
    std::set<Target> targets = { "A1", "B1", "C1" };

    while (not targets.empty() and tryFewTimes(3, targets)) {}
}
```